# Centering all inputs, labels and select elements

Tags: html, css

Im trying to center my inputs and select elements but I'm having a hard time figuring out the CSS code for them. Do I have to vertically align them, am I suppose to text-align center them? This is basically my question if anyone can help I appreciate it.

Code:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.survey {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
<p id="description"></p>

<div class="survey">

  <form id="survey-form">
    <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <br></br>
    <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email">
    <br></br>
    <label id="number-label" for="number">Favorite Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="number" name="number" min=1 max=10 placeholder="favorite 
    number">
    <br></br>
    <select name="favoritecolor" id="dropdown">
      <option disabled selected value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
</div>

</select>
<div id="radio-check">
  <input type="radio" name="favorite games" for:>Roblox</input>
  <br></br>
  <input type="radio" name="favorite">Minecraft</input>

  <br></br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Male">Male</input>
  <br></br>
  <input type="checkbox" value "Female">Female</input>
</div>


<textarea></textarea>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: you have some errors in your code. You miss a some closing tags as well as using `<br></br>` which is invalid HTML. `<br>` is an empty tag as such it has no closing tag.

Comment: PS: `<input>` is an empty tag aswell. As such there is no closing tag for it either. Means, that `<input>Text</input>` is invalid aswell. For that you have to use labels. Both `<input>´ and `<label></label>` are text elements (inline). As such they can be aligned by using `text-align: center;` on the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using <@br> FOR EVERY INPUT TAG IS NOT A GOOD IDEA & NEVER USE <@/br> JUST <@br>

```html
<HTML>
<head>
<style>

/*DEFAULT*/
body {
background-color: lightblue;
}
li{
list-style:none;
}
h1 {
text-align: center;
}
label {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
label,input,button{
display:block;
margin:10px 0px;
}
input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox]{
display:inline;
}


.survey {
margin: auto;
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 600px;
padding: 100px;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
<p id="description"></p>

<div class="survey">
<form id="survey-form">
<label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email">
<label id="number-label" for="number">Favorite Number</label>
<input type="number" id="number" name="number" min=1 max=10 placeholder="favorite number">
<select name="favoritecolor" id="dropdown">
<option disabled selected value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
</div>
</select>
<div id="radio-check">
<ul>
<li> <input type="radio" name="favorite games" for:>Roblox</input></li>
<li> <input type="radio" name="favorite">Minecraft</input></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="Male">Male</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value "Female">Female</input></li>
</ul>
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```